# How can i pass formData object through post and receive it in other php file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

How can i pass formData object through post and receive it in a php file , trying to upload a image file through ajax php .

My html , js file looks like this

```
<input type="file" id="myFileInputId" name="myFileName">

var the_file_that_was_uploaded = profile_image_input.files[0];
var form_data_obj = new FormData();
form_data_obj.append('fileToUpload',the_file_that_was_uploaded); 
form_data_obj.append("id_of_user", myId);
form_data_obj.append("text_of_quake", myTextvalue);

 xhr.onload = function(){

if(this.status == 200){
console.log(this.responseText);
}

};

xhr.onerror = function(){
console.log('Error from server side');
}

xhr.open('POST','myPHPbackEnd.php',true);
xhr.send('some_information='+form_data_obj);
```

in my php file , want to do this

```
if(isset( $_POST['some_information'])){

//how to get the file and its porperty
//cannot get to $_FILES['some_information']
//or $_FILES['myFileName']
//or id and text

}
```

I want to get the formData object and its content and pass it to a next php file for doing something like this , but cannot relate all of them together

```
$fileName = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
$fileType = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'];
$fileContent = file_get_contents($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
$dataUrl = 'data:' . $fileType . ';base64,' . base64_encode($fileContent);


$value = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = 'temp_image_folder/'.basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($value,$targetPath);
```

Comment: Woulndnt it be `$_FILES['fileToUpload']` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your js code to:

```
xhr.send(form_data_obj);
```

Then in your php do:

```
if(isset($_FILES['fileToUpload'])){
 
   // do stuff with file
}
```